# How to create a horizontal bar chart in PowerBI with time as the x-axis

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuzWt.png)

And I want to draw a  horizontal bar in PowerBI like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grH8V.png)

Where the start of the black portion starts with the values of 'Time Start' in the row, and it ends with the value of the 'Time End' in the row. And it continues the same bar from values of the next rows.

I try building as a bar chart in PowerBI, but one of the problem I see is the time gap between `Time Start' in the rows of the Tables varies.  I.e in my sample, it goes from 10:41 to 10:43 to 10:44 to 11:15.

Can you please tell me how can I do this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Gannt chart.  It isn't available out of the box in Power BI.

- Open your Power BI report and click on the ellipsis (three dots) in the Visualizations pane, then click on "Get more visuals."
- In the marketplace window, search for Gantt and installit
- when it's installed, it'll show up on the bottom of the visual selections and you can interact with it like you would with any other visual
- Drag and drop the fields: Task - the field that represents the task or activity name, Start -  use the Time Start field from your table, End - use the End Time field from your table.
- Customize the appearance, colors, etc. using the Format pane.
  This should give you a Gantt visual displaying the horizontal bar for each task with the start and end times based on your Time Start and Time End values in the table.  The gaps between the bar will represent the time gaps between the start times in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Step1. add [index] column in PowerQuery;

Step2. calculate length of time, formula as [len] column:

`Len = left([time end],2)*60+mid([time end],4,2)-(left([time start],2)*60+mid([time start],4,2))`;

Step3. use "stacked bar chart", put [len] into X axis, [index] into Legend;

Step4. set bars color with 2&4 in red, 1&3&5 in black; also data labels with 2&4 show, 1&3&5 hide.

[image: table]

[image: visual]